# Is there an R function/approach that enables you to apply a custom function to each group of a grouped data frame?

Tags: r, group-by, apply

In R, I am attempting to apply a custom function to each individual group of a dataframe (that is grouped by a particular column)
The function itself is designed to take in a subset (one group) of the whole data frame and return a modified data frame. Ideally, I would like the final output to be a single data frame with the same combined groups, but each group is modified by the function before being binded back into the whole data frame.

For example:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope'...)
month <- c('Jan','Feb','Mar'...)
monthlysalary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800...)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14')...)
 employ.data <- data.frame(employee, month, salary, startdate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to apply some custom function:

```
func = function(df_subset) {
##functions mutates monthlysalary of dataframe  - cannot include exact code for privacy reasons##
}
```

to the original data frame grouped by the column employee (`employ.data %>% group_by(employee)`) So, the function only changes the column monthly salary of each employee in isolation. The function actually considers row indexes for each group and since the groups are of unequal length, I have to apply the function to each group in isolation.

I have struggled to successfully use any of the dyplyr apply functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If your function expects a subset of dataframe we can pass do it with `split-apply-combine` approach

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(employ.data, employ.data$employee), func))
```

In `tidyverse` that could be applied with

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% group_split(employee) %>% map_df(func)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the direction. I have tried applying these with my function but I receive the following error:                                                           ***Error in df_subset$salary[1:nrow(df_subset)] : NA/NaN argument***                                                        I used the range 1:nrow(df_subset) to apply some changes to every row within the group. Any idea as to what the source of the error is? Thanks.

Comment: @learning_code It's really difficult to help without knowing how you are applying it to your real data and what the function does.

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, you can use the following code to update `salary` by groups of `employee`:

```
employ.data <- within(employ.data, salary <- ave(salary,employee,FUN = func))
```

**Example with Dummy Data**

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope','John Doe')
month <- c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Feb')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,22000)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2010-11-1'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, month, salary, startdate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# here is a dummy function that depending on the sized of subset
func <- function(x) x + 100*length(x)
```

then you will get

```
> employ.data
    employee month salary  startdate
1   John Doe   Jan  21200 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn   Feb  23500 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope   Mar  26900 2007-03-14
4   John Doe   Feb  22200 2010-11-01
```